# Why are private methods not working with polymorphism?

Tags: php, object, inheritance, polymorphism, private

Kind of got a problem using inheritance/polymorphism with private methods.

Example:

```
class cmsPage{

   private function getBlock(){
       $block = new cmsBlock();
       return $block
   }

   function createBlock(){
       $block = $this->getBlock();
       $block->save();
   }
   //... do various things
}


class specialCmsPage extends cmsPage{

   private function getBlock(){
       $block = new specialCmsBlock();
       return $block
   }

}
```

Naturally I want specialCmsPage to inherit all the methods from cmsPage. The Function `getBlock()` should make sure all Content Blocks added to specialCmsPage are of type specialCmsBlock and not cmsBlock.

I figured out, that it only works they way I expect it if I remove the "private" from the class methods, but I would prefer to use these, because these methods should not be called from outside a class. 
Upon using "**private**" in front of the `getBlock()` method specialCmsPage always receives a cmsBlock Object.

Is there a way to achieve what I want using "**private**"?

Comment: `getBlock` looks like a bad function. Why does it exist?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to initialise your specialCmsPage and run the getBlock function?

Comment: The reason getBlock existst is that I can use the original Code from "cmsPage" but have it inserting different objects when used in "specialCmsPage". I can't do that having the "new" operator inside a method, so I made a overridable method that supplies a new child object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [protected](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)?  **private** members are visible only to the class in which they are declared.  **protected** members are visible to the class and its descendants.

Comment: Protected seems to be what I was looking for, Thanks for the fast reply

Comment: Actually, from what I see default modifier (i.e. **no** modifier) is what you are looking for. Protected lets you use fields in its subclasses (even outside the package). Default modifier is more strict and it prohibits to use members from outside of the package. That's why everything worked fine when you delete the private modifier. Hope that helps.