# Class inheritance and $this variable

Tags: php

Having the code

```
class A {
    private function foo() {}
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();
        static::foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private function foo() {}
}
```

And taking what documentation says "...$this-> will try to call private methods from the same scope..."

1. What does it mean "same scope"?
2. What is the scope of "$this" in the example code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908078/private-prefix-for-methods-not-working-with-polymorphism-in-php

Comment: the current class is self:: not $this

Comment: @ Muhammet - so what's "current class/object"? A or B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording 'from the same scope'<sup>1</sup> means '*from the **same class** in which this method is defined*'.

In this case `test` is defined in the A class. Thus `$this->foo()` is going to call A's `foo` - it doesn't matter if `$this` is an A or B because `private` methods are *not* [polymorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping).

Contrast this to `protected` methods which *are* polymorphic so changing the access modifier changes the behavior; and *removes the 'same scope' clause*.

As to why this is the way it is, consider the role of the modifiers:

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes. *Members declared as private may only be accessed by the **[same] class** that defines the member.*

This means that `$this->foo()` (from A's test) *cannot* possibly call B's foo, or it would violate this restriction. Other OOP languages work similarly for the same reason: polymorphism only works the caller is allowed to access the method.

See [Why are private methods not working with polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908078/private-prefix-for-methods-not-working-with-polymorphism-in-php?lq=1) which really is a duplicate, albeit the question is written in terms of the experienced behavior.

---

<sup>1</sup> This 'same scope' wording applies to how the method is resolved, and does *not* relate to `$this` directly. The lexical scope of `$this`, a special variable, would be the current instance method; and the value of `$this` is that of the instance upon which the method was invoked.

Comment: So when interpreter hits "$this->foo" it looks for the access modifier of foo method. If it's private it means "no late binding" and "no polymorphism" because private methods cannot be overridden. If the modifier is public or protected it means "late binding" and polymorphism so it looks on what $this is referring to and since it points to $b object of class B. Am I right?

Comment: @user2864740: Nice answer, but when you say “are not polymorphic”, don’t you in fact mean “are not inherited”? Polymorphism is something different.

Comment: @lxg I am fairly certain to say 'not [subtype] polymorphic' is correct and that inheritance, including that of interfaces, is a predicate for inclusive [subtype] polymorphism. They are also not inherited

Answer (score 0):

$this is valid at the scope of the class itself, so inside class B calling $this->foo will call foo() function of class B since it is in the scope of B, if you want to call foo() of class A inside class B, you refer to it using the parent keyword :

parent::foo(), in this case foo is not in the local scope of B, it is in the parent scope.

Comment: So in my example when I use $this->foo() in "test" method of class A $this reefers to scope A or B?

Comment: It refers to class A.

Comment: But why do "get_class($this)" run in "test" method of class A retorns B not A?

Comment: Since foo is declared as private in A, when calling it from within the scope of A, even if test is called from within B, A's foo function will be called.

Comment: @Mulligan1981 Please see the question linked. If it was `protected` then the expected polymorphism would work. As you've identified $this refers to the current instance, but the problem is the `private` method is *not* polymorphic. Thus even if $this is for class B it doesn't matter because the current scope of the code is in A with a non-polymorphic method call.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) is a good read on `$this`

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from
>   within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object
>   (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another
>   object, if the method is called statically from the context of a
>   secondary object).

[PHP's visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) also can give you some insight about the scope in the class and object level.