# Unexpected inheritance behavior of php code

Tags: php

I've written this code for check behavior of my app and i don't why this code works. I have 2 classes and 1 entry point

PHP 7.2

```
class Base{

    public function check(){
       return $this->checkUnexist();
    }

}

class Main extends Base
{
    public function checkUnexist()
    {
        return 'UNEXIST METHOD CALLED';
    }
}

$main = new Main();
echo $main->check();
```

Expected result something like called method unexist. But it calls method from child class with "this". Why? And where i can read about this issue ?

Comment: The base class should not be calling methods which only exist in child classes.  Can you give a more concrete example which may help in properly creating the class structure.

Comment: You've created an object (`Main`) that has the `checkUnexist` function. Why would you expect that it doesn't get called when you try to call it?

Comment: @NigelRen i think so. But it works. Just run it.

Comment: @GregSchmidt because it calls with "this" from parent class. it is obvious

Comment: There is a difference between what works and what you should do.  PHP is far to forgiving in some respects (IMHO).

Comment: Your understanding of object inheritance is quite backwards. Read up on [Classes and Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in the PHP manual, or about object oriented programming in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class inheritance and $this variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170218/class-inheritance-and-this-variable)

Answer (score 2):

> Trying to access child values from base(parent) class is a bad design. What if in the future someone will create another class based on your parent class, forget to create that specific property you are trying to access in your parent class?

As per my understanding, When you extend the class the child class have all the property, methods available for the `Main class object`, which are accessible outside the class.

So when you created an object of `Main class` your class internally looks like

```
class Main
{
    public function checkUnexist()
    {
     return 'UNEXIST METHOD CALLED';
    }

    public function check(){
     return $this->checkUnexist();
    }
}
```

the check method exists and you will get the response. Try to make the method `checkUnexist` `private` or `protected` you will see the difference.